# Comparing area under the precision recall curve for models trained with different prevalence of the positive class

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, auc, precision-recall

I am trying to determine the optimal prevalence of the positive class to use when training my models.

I have decided to use area under the precision recall curve (AUPRC) as my metric for determining which model outperforms another, due to the results of this paper: [The Precision-Recall Plot Is More Informative
than the ROC Plot When Evaluating Binary
Classifiers on Imbalanced Datasets](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0118432&type=printable)

However, as AUPRC baseline varies depending on the prevalence of the positive class, the AUPRC can not be easily compared for models built on datasets with different prevalences of the positive class.

baseline for AUPRC = P/(P+N)
where P is the number of positives and N is the number of negatives

Should I normalise the AUPRC bu dividing by the baseline, or should I use another metric such as area under the ROC curve for determining the optimal model?

For example with a balanced dataset I obtain an AUPRC of 0.83, when the ratio of the positive to negative class is 1/10 I obtain an AUPRC of 0.67 and when the ratio is 1/100 I obtain an AUPRC of 0.23.